# multiple in condition in python

Tags: python, list

As you can see in my if statement I have multiple in conditions, how can I shorten it to only one?

I would like it be something like this for example:

```
if (['5', 'Blue'] and ['10', 'Blue'] and ['60', 'Blue']) in clicked_items:
        print("2, 2a, 3, 4, 5, 5a components are dry.")
```

My current code:

```
if ['5', 'Blue'] in clicked_items and ['10', 'Blue'] in clicked_items and ['60', 'Blue'] in clicked_items:
    print("2, 2a, 3, 4, 5, 5a components are dry.")
```

Comment: What does `clicked_items` look like? Does your current code work?

Comment: Here is an example of wat clicked_items can contain = [['60', 'Blue'], ['10', 'Blue'], ['5', 'Blue']]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes multiple similar conditions can be collapsed into an [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) or [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) call.

This line does what you ask for:

```
if all([n, 'Blue'] in clicked_items for n in ('5', '10', '60')):
```

Here is the above line used in a complete program. It prints "dry" in the first condition, and "nope" in the second.

```
clicked_items = (
   ['1', 'Red'],
   ['5', 'Blue'],
   ['10', 'Blue'],
   ['60', 'Blue'],
   ['70', 'Blue'],
)
if all([n, 'Blue'] in clicked_items for n in ('5', '10', '60')):
    print("2, 2a, 3, 4, 5, 5a components are dry.")
else:
    print("Nope")

clicked_items = (
   ['1', 'Red'],
   ['5', 'Blue'],
   ['10', 'Red'],
   ['60', 'Blue'],
   ['70', 'Blue'],
)
if all([n, 'Blue'] in clicked_items for n in ('5', '10', '60')):
    print("2, 2a, 3, 4, 5, 5a components are dry.")
else:
    print("Nope")
```

### Update

If not all of the colors were blue, then the generator expression might need to be different, like so:

```
if all([n, color] in clicked_items
       for n, color in [['60', 'Pink'], ['10', 'Blue'], ['5', 'Red']]):
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot! Is this called list comprehension btw?

Comment: No, I did not use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) in this example. The `for` loop that is passed as an argument to `any` is called a ["generator expression."](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) The two have similar syntax.

Comment: What would you do if you needed to check if for example [['60', 'Pink'], ['10', 'Blue'], ['5', 'Red']] could you edit your answer to give an example please?